# Rhino Mocks - stub out something that returns IQueryable(Of T)

Tags: linq, unit-testing, rhino-mocks

I work w/ Rhino Mocks 3.5 a lot but recently came across something I had never tried before.  I want to stub out a service and setup the return value - simple stuff really

The only issue is that now my service isn't returning IList, but instead IQueryable

So when I try to do something like this - it blows up

```
<TestMethod()> _
    Public Sub Should_Populate_Users_Property_On_View_During_OnInit()
        Dim View As IUserView = MockRepository.GenerateStub(Of IUserView)()
        Dim Service As IUserService = MockRepository.GenerateStub(Of IUserService)()
        Dim Presenter As New UserPresenter(View, Service)

        Dim StubUserObjectCollection As New List(Of User)
        StubUserObjectCollection.Add(New User(1, "jdoe", "John", "Doe", 0, 0, 0, 1, 1))

        Service.Stub(Function(x) x.GetUserCollection()).[Return](StubUserObjectCollection)

        Presenter.OnViewInit()

        Assert.AreEqual(View.Users.Count, 1)
    End Sub
```

How can I stub out the service to enable a unit test for the below (kept simple for brevity)

```
Public Sub OnViewInit()
    Dim UserList As List(Of User) = mUserService.GetUserCollection.Where(Function(x) x.Active = 1).OrderBy(Function(x) x.FirstName).ToList()

    mView.Users = UserList
End Sub
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Can you not change your StubUserObjectCollection to be an IQueryable?

```
Dim SubList As New List(Of User)
StubList.Add(New User(1, "jdoe", "John", "Doe", 0, 0, 0, 1, 1))
Dim StubUserObjectCollection = StubList.AsQueryable();
```

Comment: I knew it had to be something simple that I missed!  Thanks for the quick reply!